# Silverstripe: Filtering a $DataObject::get()

Tags: php, silverstripe, data-objects

I'm building an archive page and I'm having trouble pulling and filtering my results by year.

The page type has a dropdown to select which year should be displayed

```
private static $db = array(
    "SubType" => "Enum(array('2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'))"
);
```

The template calls a function GetFilms

```
public function GetFilms()
{
    $films = DataObject::get("Film");
    return $films;
}
```

If I use the function above it works but displays all the films.

When I try to modify it to filter using the year its been passed,

```
public function GetFilms($SubType)
{
    $films = DataObject::get("Film","'Year' = '$SubType'");
    return $films;
}
```

The page no longer displays any of the films.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code for displaying the results,

```
<% loop GetFilms($SubType) %>
    <div class="film" data-title="$Title">
        <a href="$Top.Link?film=$ID">
        <div class="inner">
            <h3 class="filmTitle">$Title</h3>
            <img class="filmImg" src="$FilmImage.URL" alt="$Title" />
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<% end_loop %>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'd suggest is doing some debugging. You can add some points into `GetFilms()` e.g. `var_dump($SubType);` to see what the template is passing in. You should check that your Film DataObjects can be accessed manually by using dummy values, e.g. `Film::get()->filter(['Year' => 2013])`, then once you've eliminated the data source and the method's input as problem areas you can piece it back together.

I'd also suggest moving away from `DataObject::get` arguments to a chainable approach using DataList methods, e.g.:

```
public function GetFilms($SubType)
{
    return Film::get()->filter(['Year' => $SubType]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!
I've done a var_dump and it is receiving the correct date.  I've also tried using raw sql,
    $films = DB::query("SELECT * FROM `film` WHERE `Year` = '2016'")->value();
but I run into the same problem, no films show up. I've run that exact sql in phpmyadmin and it returned results.
I've tried appending /?showqueries to the url to check the query but it looks fine

Comment: I wonder if it could be the fact that your column is called 'Year' (reserved word in MySQL)

Comment: I've changed the column to 'FilmYear' and updated the function. 

The DataObject::get("Film","'FilmYear' = '$SubType'"); doesn't work.

DB::query("SELECT * FROM `film` WHERE `FilmYear` = '2016'")->value(); doesn't work.

But your initial suggestion, return Film::get()->filter(['FilmYear' => $SubType]); works.  I don't have a clue why that works when the others don't.

Answer (score 0):

remove extra '' from $SubType to
ie $films = DataObject::get("Film","'Year' = $SubType");
when you put single quote the  $SubType, become literal and does not evaluate the value

Comment: That's not true

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I don't  notice outer double quote

Comment: try this DataObject::get("Film","Year = '$SubType'"); without '' for  Year